# scale in data.table in r

Tags: r, data.table, scale

```
       LC  RC TOEIC eua again  class
   1: 490 390   880  90     0 100818
   2: 495 395   890  90     0 100818
   3: 490 330   820  90     0 100818
   4: 495 460   955  96     0 100818
   5: 495 370   865  91     0 100818
  ---                               
1021: 470 400   870  61     0 100770
1022: 260 180   440  48     0 100770
1023: 345 190   535  39     0 100770
1024: 450 295   745  65     0 100770
1025: 395 230   625  79     0 100770
```

This `data.table` is named "analy"

I want to scale the variables "LC","RC","TOEIC","eua". 
I can scale as below

```
analy[,LC:=scale(LC)]
analy[,RC:=scale(RC)]
analy[,TOEIC:=scale(TOEIC)]
analy[,eua:=scale(eua)]
```

but, I want to know how to scale the variables at once.

Answer (score 15):

```
analy[ , c("LC", "RC", "TOEIC", "eua") := lapply(list(LC, RC, TOEIC, eua), scale)]
```

---

A little more convenient way of doing it would be (as @David mentions under comment):

```
cols <- c("LC", "RC", "TOEIC", "eua")
analy[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, scale), .SDcols=cols]
```

Note the `(` around `cols` is necessary so that `cols` is evaluated to get the column names, and then modify them by reference. This is so that we can still continue doing: `DT[ ,col := val]`.

Comment: `analy[, c("LC", "RC", "TOEIC", "eua") := lapply(.SD, scale), .SDcols = c("LC", "RC", "TOEIC", "eua")]` would be a more correct way of doing this

Comment: I don't think using `lapply` as suggested above works.  It does compute something, but something wrong for all columns except the first one.  I'm not sure why, but I found a way around that - See my answer with reproducible results below.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to a more general question on pre-processing columns in data.table using `.SD` posted here: [Computing inter-value differences in data.table columns (with .SD) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191486/computing-inter-value-differences-in-data-table-columns-with-sd-in-r).

Here's the answer to your question, and what you will get if you use `scale()` function incorrectly:

```
DT <- data.table(K=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)), X=(1:10)^2, Y=2^(1:10))
cols <- 2:3;  cols.d0 = paste0("d0.", names(DT)[cols])

# Correct and incorrect use of scale() with data.table

# Works for one column.
DT[, d0_Y:= scale(Y), keyby=K][]

# RUNS BUT GIVES WRONG RESULT! ==> returns 1:20 data.table!
DT[, scale(.SD), keyby=K, .SDcols=cols][]

# RUNS WITH WARNING AND GIVES WRONG RESULT! - d0.X is computed correctly, by d0.Y not (compare to d0_Y) !
DT[, (cols.d0) := scale(.SD), keyby=K, .SDcols=cols][]
>     K   X    Y       d0_Y        d0.X        d0.Y
   1: 1   1    2 -0.8525736 -1.03417538 -1.03417538
   ...

# DOESN'T RUN ! - ERROR
DT[, (cols.d0) := lapply(.SD, scale), keyby=K, .SDcols=cols][]

# WORKS CORRECTLY AS DESIRED !
DT[, (cols.d0) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.vector(scale(x))), keyby=K, .SDcols=cols][]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following answer works.

```
library(data.table)
# Data 
dt <- iris
setDT(dt)

# columns to apply the scale function
cols <- colnames(dt)[-5]

# standerdize
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.vector(scale(x))),
                                      by = Species, .SDcols = cols]
```

Since `scale` returns a matrix, `as.vector` is used to convert to a vector.