# How to compute inter-value differences in data.table columns (with .SD) by groups?

Tags: r, data.table

I need to calculate relative changes of column values with respect to N-th value. See code below:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(K=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)), X=(1:10)^2, Y=2^(1:10))

df[, d.X1:= X - shift(X,fill=0,type="lag"),keyby=K][]  # WORKS
df[, d.X0:= X - .SD[3,X],keyby=K][] # WORKS

cols <- 2:3; 
cols.d1 = paste0("d1.", names(df)[cols]);  
cols.d0 = paste0("d0.", names(df)[cols])
df[, (cols.d1) := .SD - shift(.SD,fill=0,type="lag"),keyby=K, .SDcols=cols][]  # WORKS
df[, (cols.d0) := .SD - .SD[3,names(.SD)[cols]], keyby=K, .SDcols=cols]  # <=== DOESN'T WORK
```

As code above shows:
- I know how to do it using `shift()` - to compute difference between adjacent row values, for a single and multiple columns using .SD /.SDcols.
-  I also know how to compute differences with respect to N-th element for a single column (N=3 in this example).

Here  is the output

```
    K   X    Y d.X1 d.X0 d1.X d1.Y
 1: 1   1    2    1   -8   1   2
 2: 1   4    4    3   -5   3   2
 3: 1   9    8    5    0   5   4
 4: 1  16   16    7    7   7   8
 5: 1  25   32    9   16   9  16
 6: 2  36   64   36  -28  36  64
 7: 2  49  128   13  -15  13  64
 8: 2  64  256   15    0  15 128
 9: 2  81  512   17   17  17 256
10: 2 100 1024   19   36  19 512
```

However, I can't figure out how to compute differences with respect to N-th element for multiple columns (which will produce d0.X and d0.Y columns as attempted in the last line of the above code). Please help

Comment: What language/environment is that?

Comment: Not sure why you're doing `.SD[3, names(.SD)[cols]]`, maybe you want `.SD[3]` there. Also I guess you have a typo, assigning to cols.d instead of cols.d0 or cols.d1?

Comment: .SD[3] returns the entire 3rd row, thus producing error (Just try yourself - I fixed typo in code.Tx)    -   Interestingly, what I'm trying to achieve is one of key data pre-processing steps in signal processing, when the N-th measurement is used as a baseline, so that all other measurements are considered in relationship to baseline signal. There must be an easy way to do it !

Comment: Well, .SD is the row filtered to whatever elements you have included in .SDcols, namely cols, so filtering with that variable again doesn't do anything special even if you use correct syntax (the `with=FALSE` argument, see `?data.table`). You could try `lapply(.SD, function(z) z - z[3])` if I understand correctly. Btw, I see the error you mention... a kludgy workaround is `.SD-.SD[rep(3,.N)]`

Comment: Both `df[, (cols.d0) := lapply(.SD, function(z) z - z[3]) , keyby=K, .SDcols=cols]`   and  `df[, (cols.d0) := .SD-.SD[rep(3,.N)] , keyby=K, .SDcols=cols]` work! Neat. Thanks! If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Frank's comment above:

Both

```
 df[, (cols.d0) := lapply(.SD, function(z) z - z[3]) , keyby=K, .SDcols=cols]
```

and

```
df[, (cols.d0) := .SD-.SD[rep(3,.N)] , keyby=K, .SDcols=cols] []
```

work. Below is the desired output:

```
   K   X    Y d.X1 d.X0 d1.X d1.Y d0.X d0.Y
 1: 1   1    2    1   -8    1    2   -8   -6
 2: 1   4    4    3   -5    3    2   -5   -4
 3: 1   9    8    5    0    5    4    0    0
 4: 1  16   16    7    7    7    8    7    8
 5: 1  25   32    9   16    9   16   16   24
 6: 2  36   64   36  -28   36   64  -28 -192
 7: 2  49  128   13  -15   13   64  -15 -128
 8: 2  64  256   15    0   15  128    0    0
 9: 2  81  512   17   17   17  256   17  256
10: 2 100 1024   19   36   19  512   36  768
```