# R: Scaling Every Column in Data.Table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with 37000 rows and 27000 columns. I want to pre-process and scale each column before using the data for a prediction task.

I am using the approach mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260891/scale-in-data-table-in-r) post but find it works very slowly, even crashing R Studio. I have attached the approach below, for reference. Is there a faster method for scaling all columns of a large data.table?

```
scale.cols <- colnames(DT)
DT[, (scale.cols) := lapply(.SD, scale), .SDcols = scale.cols]
```

Comment: I think `scale` is just at it's most basic a `z` score calculator, so you could replace `scale` with `function(x) (x - mean(x))/sd(x)` and it will probably speed things up dramatically.

Comment: if one was using `data.table` however, probably want to iterate and use `set()` since the number of columns is large.

Comment: @zacdav if you call `[` once then it won't be an issue, many `set` is much better than many `[` calls

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can have the data in a matrix format first since it will not be very fast in `data.table` for large number of columns, then one possibility is to use `RcppArmadillo`

`scale.cpp`:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat armaScale(arma::mat Z) {
    unsigned int j, n = Z.n_rows, k = Z.n_cols;
    double avg, sd;
    arma::colvec z;
    arma::mat res = arma::zeros(n, k);

    for (j=0; j<k; j++) {
        z = Z.col(j);
        avg = arma::mean(z);
        sd = arma::stddev(z);
        res.col(j) = (z - avg) / sd;
    }

    return res;
}
```

R code:

```
set.seed(0L)
#using a smaller dataset
s <- 2e3
nr <- 3*s
nc <- 2*s
mat <- matrix(rnorm(nr*nc), ncol=nc)

library(RcppArmadillo)
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("scale.cpp")

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(armaScale(mat), scale(mat), times=3L)
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
           expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 armaScale(mat)  272.4988  290.1339  303.5027  307.7689  319.0047  330.2404     3  a 
     scale(mat) 1290.9581 1400.7916 1445.8927 1510.6251 1523.3600 1536.0950     3   b
```

Comment: Not sure it's appropriate to benchmark on a small example. OP specifically referring to a case where input data size is 10Gb, roughly

Comment: @MichaelChirico. I agree with you, but I am facing RAM limitations.in the end, it will be 2 * 999mio (the original matrix and the resulting) numbers that need to be stored.

Comment: I think there's ample wiggle room between 600*400 case and 37000*27000 case; i'm always skeptical of benchmarks that measure in milliseconds, especially in the case when the actual use case is likely to last quite a bit longer

Comment: did u mean 6000*4000 instead?