# R Normalize Many Columns

Tags: r, data.table, normalize

```
data = data.frame(cat = runif(1000), dog = runif(1000), fox = runif(1000), bunny = runif(1000))
normalize_these = c("dog", "bunny")
```

I wish to obtain a new version of data called dataNEW where the variable columns listed in 'normalize_these' are normalized with mean equals to 0 and standard deviation equals to 1. Is there a data.table solution to do so?

Comment: Converting variables to mean zero and unit sd is called standardization. Normalizing means when you convert variables to be in the range 0 to 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scale in data.table in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260891/scale-in-data-table-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `scale` like below

```
cbind(data, `colnames<-`(scale(data[normalize_these]), paste0(normalize_these, "NEW")))
```

---

If you would like to use `data.table`, below might be an option

```
setDT(data)
data[, paste0(normalize_these, "NEW") := lapply(.SD, scale), .SDcols = normalize_these]
```

Comment: that is great thank you what if I wish to tack on a "NORMALIZED" so I add two new data columns "dogNORMALIZE" and "bunnyNORMALIZED"